# pandas dataframe dtypes compare equality

Tags: python, pandas, equality

How can I see which `dtypes` in a pandas data frame are not equal?

I.e. to find out why `df1.dtypes.equals(df2.dtypes)` returns `False`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as the column names match and you have the same number of columns then you can just compare the `dtypes` directly:

```
In [152]:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'int':np.arange(5), 'flt':np.random.randn(5)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'int':np.random.randn(5), 'flt':np.random.randn(5)})
df1.dtypes == df2.dtypes

Out[152]:
flt     True
int    False
dtype: bool
```